# AngularJS: How to trigger ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My controller fails in production. Once I correct the problem, I instantiate the controller manually, but ng-repeat is not processed:

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  var isBreak = true;
  var Acme={};
  var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .controller("Foo", function($scope, $timeout) {
    if(isBreak) {
      isBreak = false;
      throw "stuff";
    }
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.stuff = ["one", "two"];
    })
  })
  .run(function($rootScope, $compile, $timeout) {
    Acme.$rootScope = $rootScope;
    Acme.$compile = $compile;
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <div ng-controller="Foo">

      <p ng-repeat="s in stuff">{{s}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I type in the console:

```
Acme.$compile($("#parent").contents())(Acme.$rootScope)
```

The other postings to this same question have accepted answers but they do NOT solve the problem.
(I am showing the "fake" exception above for illustration. In the real code, the exception is caused by something else.)

Comment: Fails with what error? Do you minify your code in production?

Comment: What is the actual problem? What is the *actual* error?

Comment: And where is the line that attempts to read `point_rewards`?

Comment: That file is 1700 lines long. I created a stripped-down version of the code to show what the issue is. I want to reinstantiate the controller and see ng-repeat render. Thanks!